# How to make a Payment link of paytm through api in my react native app without adding a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, payment

For example, if someone fills up all information and his total order cost is 15000 rs then the app needs to make a Paytm payment link with that amount of money and then open it in a web view in order for the payment to be done.

Could you please help me or have any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Paytm required signature to verify the authentication in all the paytm link api. To generate the signature you require to add server, so it will not be possible through react native app itself.